# Python Pandas - count string found in column so far for every row

Tags: python, pandas

I am doing some analysis and visuals on past NHL seasons and I'm having difficulty in creating some additional data/features in my DataFrame.

This is a simplified version of the dataframe where each row represents one game.

```
game_id h_abbr a_abbr 
0001    WSH    TOR 
0002    ANA    TOR 
0003    TOR    MIN
```

How can I count how many games each team has played so far (including the game in question) so the new column would look like something like this?

```
game_id h_abbr a_abbr ht_game_no at_game_no
0001    WSH    TOR    1          1
0002    ANA    TOR    1          2
0003    TOR    MIN    3          1
```

After a lot of searching and trying I have only found a way to count how many home OR away games the team has played, but I am interested in the total games played.

```
df['Nth_away_game'] = df.groupby('a_abbr').cumcount() + 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is reshape values by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), then use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html), check columns names by [`DataFrame.add_suffix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html) and last [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to original:

```
s = df[['h_abbr','a_abbr']].stack()
df = df.join(s.groupby(s).cumcount().add(1).unstack().add_suffix('_no'))
print (df)
   game_id h_abbr a_abbr  h_abbr_no  a_abbr_no
0        1    WSH    TOR          1          1
1        2    ANA    TOR          1          2
2        3    TOR    MIN          3          1
```

Comment: Thank you jezrael. Works like charm!